# How to display icon with text in the toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, optionmenu

I am getting problem in adding icon with text in the toolbar.I have tried the following code:

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_new_group, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.createGroup:
            createNewGroup();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**menu_new_group.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createGroup"
        android:icon="@drawable/single_tick"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Create"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

Only single tick is displayed in the toolbar .Title is not displayed. Please help .

**Updated code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createGroup"
        android:icon="@drawable/single_tick"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText|always"
        android:title="Create" />
</menu>
```

Still not working for me.Please view the following screenshot:

[image]

Icon is not displayed here.I want icon and text on the toolbar.

**activity_new_group.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBarNewGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10">

        <com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/groupPic"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        <com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_camera_group"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin30"
            android:background="@drawable/color"
            android:src="@drawable/camera1" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_border_orange"
        android:hint="Type group subject here ..."
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_friends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you display output

Comment: I think your Create button is overlapping the Toolbar. Share your layout code

Answer (score 14):

I have resolved this problem by following code:

1- Create menu in menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_sign"
    android:title="签到"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_sign" />
```

2- `app:actionLayout` is the key word, Then create layout named menu_sign and put textView in it. the icon will displayed by drawableLeft

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_user_sign"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:text="@string/text"
   android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_5"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_10"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

3- Add listener for your menu

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sign, menu);
    signItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sign);
    signItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(signItem);
        }
    });
```

4- Then you will get the menu and listener

Comment: I second that, best solution! Keeps it all within the XML of the menu.

Comment: how to set text in textview ?

Comment: For @Chielarck Question: TextView tv = (TextView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_counter).getActionView();

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap `TextView` with Toolbar as follows to fully Customize it. With TextView you can use `drawableLeft` or `drawlableRight` to specify the icon.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
            android:drawableLeft="Your_Draable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion is working for me ,but gravity is not working.I want to align the textview to the right of toolbar.How to achieve this?

Comment: It is not displayed in the text view and is also not working for toolbar

Comment: Note that auto completion will not work for `android:layout_gravity="right"`, you need to copy/past it.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It is working for me now.Please edit your code and write the android:layout_gravity="right".I will mark your answer as correct .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use default menu bar You have to override your layout. Otherwise You can use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) which is totally customizable and very easy to implement.

Comment: I am using toolbar here and adding menu here which is displaying singletick icon only

Comment: Great. Use a toolbar but instead of using menu xml file add your menu items in your toolbar layout as mentioned by @Shajeel. it is way easier.